# Python partition and split

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, split, partition

I want to split a string with two words like "word1 word2" using split and partition and print (using a for) the words separately like:

```
Partition:
word1
word2

Split:
word1
word2
```

This is my code:

```
print("Hello World")
name = raw_input("Type your name: ")

train = 1,2
train1 = 1,2
print("Separation with partition: ")
for i in train1:
    print name.partition(" ")

print("Separation with split: ")
for i in train1:
    print name.split(" ")
```

This is happening:

```
Separation with partition: 
('word1', ' ', 'word2')
('word1', ' ', 'word2')

Separation with split: 
['word1', 'word2']
['word1', 'word2']
```

Comment: This post is useful for reference, but I have absolutely no idea what **question** OP had in mind.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A command like `name.split()` returns a list. You might consider iterating over that list:

```
for i in name.split(" "):
  print i
```

Because the thing you wrote, namely

```
for i in train:
  print name.split(" ")
```

will execute the command `print name.split(" ")` twice (once for value `i=1`, and once more for `i=2`). And twice it will print out the entire result:

```
['word1', 'word2']
['word1', 'word2']
```

A similar thing happens with `partition` - except it returns the element that you split as well. So in that case you might want to do

```
print name.partition(" ")[0:3:2]
# or
print name.partition(" ")[0::2]
```

to return elements `0` and `2`. Alternatively, you can do

```
train = (0, 2,)
for i in train:
  print name.partition(" ")[i]
```

To print element 0 and 2 in two consecutive passes through the loop. Note that this latter code is more inefficient as it computes the partition twice. If you cared, you could write

```
train = (0,2,)
part = name.partition(" ")
for i in train:
  print part[i]
```

Comment: Hi Floris, What does this line mean, "except it returns the element that you split as well"? `.partition(sep)` returns `first`, `sep`, `tail`, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes - i meant that the second element is `sep` which you probably don’t want to print.

Answer (score 31):

[`str.partition`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) returns a tuple of three elements. String before the partitioning string, the partitioning string itself and the rest of the string. So, it has to be used like this

```
first, middle, rest = name.partition(" ")
print first, rest
```

To use the [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), you can simply print the splitted strings like this

```
print name.split(" ")
```

But, when you call it like this, if the string has more than one space characters, you will get more than two elements. For example

```
name = "word1 word2 word3"
print name.split(" ")          # ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
```

If you want to split only once, you can specify the number times to split as the second parameter, like this

```
name = "word1 word2 word3"
print name.split(" ", 1)       # ['word1', 'word2 word3']
```

But, if you are trying to split based on the whitespace characters, you don't have to pass `" "`. You can simply do

```
name = "word1 word2 word3"
print name.split()            # ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
```

If you want to limit the number of splits,

```
name = "word1 word2 word3"
print name.split(None, 1)     # ['word1', 'word2 word3']
```

**Note:** Using `None` in `split` or specifying no parameters, this is what happens

Quoting from the [split documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is
>   applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single
>   separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start
>   or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently,
>   splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace
>   with a None separator returns [].

So, you can change your program like this

```
print "Partition:"
first, middle, rest = name.partition(" ")
for current_string in (first, rest):
    print current_string

print "Split:"
for current_string in name.split(" "):
    print current_string
```

Or you can use [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method like this

```
print "Partition:"
first, middle, rest = name.partition(" ")
print "\n".join((first, rest))

print "Split:"
print "\n".join(name.split())
```